# Magnitude of instantaneous velocity vs speed

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors, speed

Magnitude of instantaneous velocity = $|dr/dt|$ but this is not always equal to $ds/dt$ where ds is the infinitesimally small change in *distance* in the interval $dt$

Which one is speed?

[image]

Comment: Why would they not be equal?  For both you are only travelling an infinitesimal amount.  The difference between $\Delta r$ and $\Delta s$ goes away as $\Delta$ becomes smaller.  In this case it's $ds$ and $dr$ which is the limit where they become equal.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? Also, is this always the case? (Instantaneous speed being equal to the modulus of dr/dt and also equal to ds/dt?)

Comment: Sure, I just thought there might have been something from the question that I misinterpreted.  It's also good practice to wait before accepting answers in case a better one comes along; but I'll leave that to your judgement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both you are only travelling an infinitesimal amount.

The difference between $\Delta r$ and $\Delta s$ goes away as $\Delta$ becomes smaller. In this case it's $ds$ and $dr$ which is the limit where they become equal.

You can look at your drawing and imagine as you decrease r and s, the space between the line $dr$ and the arc of the circle will keep getting smaller until at an infinitesimally small value they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely,

\begin{align*}
  s &=\int |\mathbf{v}| \, dt \\
  \frac{ds}{dt} &= |\mathbf{v}| \\
  &= \left| \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} \right| \\
  ds &= |d\mathbf{x}| \\
  &= |\mathbf{v}| \, dt
\end{align*}

For linear motion without *"U-turn"*, we can mix the usage of $s$ and $x$.

Comment: Really thank you for the mathematical description, I was looking for this